# R data frame replacement error

Tags: r

I'm trying to replicate some work and running into a `dataframe` error. I'm trying to subset just year 2011 of my data. And show the difference in the lag between my two variables (LnCO & LnPP).

## Data Formating for PP Regressions

```
PP$LnCO_diff1 <- PP$LnCO - PP$LnCO_1
```

This is the error I am receiving:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "LnCO_diff1", value = numeric(0)) : 
>         replacement has 0 rows, data has 433

I'm fairly new to R and have no idea. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), especially [one for r](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? `mtcars$fake = mtcars$gear-mtcars$carb` works fine.

Comment: Please, show the contents of PP, or show what `str(PP)` returns at least.